# How to revise apalike reference style format?

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

The current format and code I am using are as follows:

`\bibliography{references}`

`\bibliographystyle{apalike}`

An example of the reference is this:

```
@article{aiello1995electronic,

  title={Electronic performance monitoring and social context: Impact on productivity and stress.},

  author={Aiello, John R and Kolb, Kathryn J},

  journal={Journal of Applied Psychology},

  volume={80},

  number={3},

  pages={339--353},

  year={1995},

  publisher={American Psychological Association

  \url= \url{https://doi.org/10.1037/0021-9010.80.3.339}}
}
```

The output shows like this:

[image]

However, the format I want to make is like this (the revisions I want to make are highlighted in bold):

Aiello, J. R., **&** Kolb, K. J. (1995). Electronic performance monitoring and social context: Impact on productivity and stress. ***Journal of Applied Psychology, 80***(3)**,** 339-353. **https://doi.org/10.1037/0021-9010.80.3.339**

That is,

1. change "and" to "&";
2. italic volume as well;
3. change ":" to ",";
4. add a clickable hyperlink with the same font format as my content (New Times Roman).

For making the above four revisions, I tried coding the reference like this:

```
@article{aiello1995electronic,

  title={Electronic performance monitoring and social context: Impact on productivity and stress.},

  author={Aiello, John R \& Kolb, Kathryn J},

  journal={Journal of Applied Psychology},

  note={\textit{80}(3), 339--353.  

      \url{https://doi.org/10.1037/0021-9010.80.3.339}},

  year={1995},

  publisher={American Psychological Association}
}
```

The output is like this:

[image]

However, the hyperlink font style is not New Times Roman.

May I ask if there are any more convenient ways to change the current APA format to the format I want to make?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `apalike` style is very old, and probably shouldn't be used as a basis for anything. If you need to do extensive changes to an author/year type style you should either create your own `.bst` file using `custombib` or, probably easier use `biblatex` with the `authoryear` or `ext-authoryear` style as a base. I'm deliberately *not* suggesting the `biblatex` `apa` style, since it's not designed to be modified.

Comment: If you wish to continue to use BibTeX and if you're ok with using the APA6 formatting guidelines, I suggest you switch to loading the `apacite` citation management package and the `apacite` bibliography style. Whatever else you do, *do not* replace the BibTeX keyword `and` in the `author` fields with `\&`.

Comment: To add to what @Mico says, if you are looking for *conforming* APA style then of course you can use `apacite` (for APA6) or the `biblatex` `apa` style, which implements APA7 (or with option APA6) style very well. But if you're using APA style loosely (as is common) and need a custom author/year style that's not conforming, then the `biblatex` `apa` style isn't the place to start. See [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793) for some discussion of the terms.